# Android: how to make multi-module dagger component injection?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have android `gradle multi-module` `dagger` application.

Inside each module I'm doing inject via it's own component like this:

`MainApp.appComponent.inject(this)` for module `:app` and
`BaseApp.appComponent.inject(this)` for module `:app:base`.

Now trying to make `SharedPreferences` wrapper available within `app:base` module. Until this point everything worked fine, but after this I faced this error

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.alazar.tracker/com.alazar.tracker.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property appComponent has not been initialized`

`Application.name` property specified at Manifest.xml of the `:app:base` module.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix that? Thanks for any suggestion.

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    @Inject
    lateinit var userManager: UserManagerInterface

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferences: PreferenceProvider

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        MainApp.appComponent.inject(this)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        binding.btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.btnStart.setOnClickListener(this)
        binding.btnStop.setOnClickListener(this)

        if (!userManager.isAuthenticated()) {
            openPostActivity.launch(Intent(this, AuthActivity::class.java))
        } else {
            setContentView(binding.root)
            changeStatus(preferences.getServiceStatus())
        }
    }

}
```

MainApp:

```
    @MainScope
@Component(
    dependencies = [
    ],
    modules = [
        MainModule::class,
    ]
)

interface MainAppComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
    fun inject(activity: MapActivity)
}

@Module(
    includes = [
        AuthUserModule::class,
        BaseModule::class,
    ]
)
class MainModule


class MainApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerMainAppComponent
            .builder()
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var appComponent: MainAppComponent
    }
}
```

BaseApp:

```
    @Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        BaseModule::class,
    ]
)

interface BaseComponent {
    fun inject(baseApp: BaseApp)
    fun inject(wrapper: SharedPrefWrapper)
}

@Module
class BaseModule constructor(private val application: Application) {
    @Provides
    fun provideContext() : Context = application.applicationContext

    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreferences() : PreferenceProvider = SharedPrefWrapper(application.applicationContext)
}

class BaseApp : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerBaseComponent
            .builder()
            .baseModule(BaseModule(this))
            .build()
    }

    companion object {
        lateinit var appComponent: BaseComponent
    }
}
```

SharedPreferences wrapper

```
    class SharedPrefWrapper @Inject constructor(private val context: Context) : PreferenceProvider {

    init {
        BaseApp.appComponent.inject(this)
        Log.d("************ CONTEXT", context.toString())
    }

    private var preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
        context.getString(R.string.shared_preference_name),
        AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
    )

    override fun saveServiceStatus(status: Boolean) {
        val editor = preferences.edit()
        editor.putBoolean(context.getString(R.string.preference_service_param), status)
        editor.apply()
    }

    override fun getServiceStatus(): Boolean {
        return preferences.getBoolean(context.getString(R.string.preference_service_param), false)
    }
}
```